# How to remove request attribute without the use of scriptlet?

Tags: jsp

```
<%request.removeAttribute("name"); %>
```

How to remove the "name" attribute with request scope in jsp ?(without scriptlet)

Answer (score 0):

The JSTL has a `<c:remove>` tag:

```
<c:remove var="name" scope="request"/>
```

That said, JSPs are view components, used to generate markup. They should read attributes, but not set and remove them, IMHO.